# Doctrine 2 - single table inheritance - access property of child entity

Tags: sql, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have simple table inheritance on my entities, say something like:

```
/** 
* @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
* @DiscriminatorMap({"base"="BaseArticle", "extended"="ExtendedArticle"}) 
*/         
class BaseArticle extends \Models\BaseModel{
   ...
}
class ExtendedArticle extends BaseArticle{
    /**
    * @column(type="string")
    */
    protected $extendedProperty;
}
```

I need to do a query across all article types, but in some types restrict the query by some property, that is in extended ExtendedArticle, ie:

```
SELECT a FROM BaseArticle a WHERE (a INSTANCE OF BaseAricle) OR (a INSTANCE OF ExtendedArticle AND a.extendedProperty = "xy")
```

Which gives me following exception:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 406 near 'extendedProperty="xy"))': Error: Class Models\Articles\BaseArticle has no field or association named location

So question is, how to access child's properties in query to parent class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Here's a workaround:

```
SELECT a
FROM BaseArticle a
WHERE
    a INSTANCE OF BaseAricle
    OR a.id IN (
        SELECT ea.id
        FROM ExtendedArticle ea
        WHERE ea.extendedProperty = "xy"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't like the idea to do such a inefficient subquery for simple thing. In SQL, this is really simple task, seems to me that doctrine needs some native support for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding `$extendedProperty` into `BaseArticle` and using getters/setters to effectively hide this property in my `BaseArticle` entity and lifecycle callbacks to handle NULLABLE. But this is really bad solution as the inheritance is almost pointless.